# Global variable and error when the function is running in Octave

Tags: octave, gnu

Program (programmatically implement) the problem of solving the rigid equation eq = -lambda * (y-sin (x)) using the ode45 solver in the Octave environment.

[image]

There is code

```
lambda=10#Global variable for function

function slv=fi(x)#Equation solution
  C=1+(lambda/(1+pow2(lambda)));
  slv=C*exp(-lambda*x)-(lambda/(1+pow2(lambda)))*(-lambda*sin(x)+cos(x));
end

#The initial function of the equation
function y=g(t,x)
  y=-lambda*(x-sin(t));–1 ERROR
end

%Determination of parameters for controlling the course of the equation
optio=odeset("RelTol",1e-5,"AbsTol",1e-5,'InitialStep',0.025,'MaxStep',0.1);


[XX,YY]=ode45(@g,[0 0.25],2,optio); - 2 ERROR

#Exact solution
x1=0:0.05:0.25;
y1=fi(x1);

%Function solution graph with ode45 and exact solution
plot(x1,y1,'-g:exact solution;',XX,YY,'*b;ode45;');
grid on;
```

But there are some errors:

```
lambda = 10
error: 'lambda' undefined near line 11, column 11
error: called from
    g at line 11 column 4
    runge_kutta_45_dorpri at line 103 column 12
    integrate_adaptive at line 135 column 39
    ode45 at line 241 column 12
    LabWork6 at line 18 column 8
```

Due to the lambda variable in the function, the error moved to another part of the program.
What did I do wrong when declaring a lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables at 'global' scope in a script are not visible from within functions, even if defined on the command-line instead of their own file, as it the proper way.

This makes sense if you think about it, because command-line functions are just convenience syntax, and a file-defined function would have no idea that some other script defines a variable somewhere, unless you use the `global` keyword to tell it about that variable.

So either declare lambda as `global` both outside and inside your function, or simply wrap your entire script inside a function, which then allows 'nested' functions to see/inherit  parent-function variables.